# Ads appearing in our application when they should not be

Tags: security, malware

I had a strange issue from one of my customers this morning, who use my web application. Apparently they are getting "ads" within the browser window when using my application.

I do not put ads in at all. It a straight forward asp.net web application.

What I believe is happening in this case is that the end user has some malware on their pc which "hops" onto their browser session to display their "wares". It could happen to any website they are perusing I guess. I recommended they scan their pc with Malwarebytes.

Is this something that is under the control of the end user, or are there things web application developers can do to prevent this happening. Also some pointers as to how these "ad browser hijackers" work would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this question to http://Security.stackexchange.com where it's probably more appropriate. In any case, user's computer must be inspected for malware toolbars in browsers etc.